# List with array only some formats files n folder and subdirectory php on Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, linux, server

I need to list all files for example mp4 or avi in my folder /Files and relative subdirectories and after that insert into `<a href={$filename}><\a>` tag so I need a array i suppose.
I tried with find command but I receive a string and not a Array so I've to split the string and this isn't practical.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

or use class `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` - For example :

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__)); 
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator);

foreach ($iterator as $filename) 
{

    if (dirname($filename) != dirname(__FILE__)) 
    {
        if(is_file($filename)) {

            $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
            if($path_parts['extension'] == 'mp4' )
            {
                print '<a href="'.$filename.'">'.basename($filename)."</a><br />";
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: there's a way to filter format files in an elegant manner or i should use `$path_parts['extension'] == 'avi' || $path_parts['extension'] == 'mp4'` ?

Comment: If all files are videos use `mime_content_type()` :

Comment: `$mime = mime_content_type($filename);
   if(preg_match('/video/', $mime))
            {
                print '<a href="'.$filename.'">'.$filename ."</a><br />";
            }`
Is correct? I don't see the output... Sorry I don't know how to indent in comments

Comment: Try width `finfo_file()` :

Comment: `$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
if(preg_match('/video/', $mime))`...

Comment: yes i've searched the use of finfo and resolved
`if(preg_match('/video/', finfo_file($finfo, $filename)))` like you... Thank you very mutch!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dir ="/Files";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $fullname = "/Files/" . $file;
    echo '<a href='.$fullname.'>File</a>;  
}
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I like this, but it don't print the subdirectory and not only mp4 or avi or others